# Elliptic curve cryptography G*G

Tags: elliptic-curves

I understand how ECC works for the point multiplications and stuff. 
All we normally do is to multiply a scalar number (lets say d as a private key) with the base point generator `G` to get a public key point on an elliptic curve. 
I am trying to tweak the algorithm for some other purposes so I am just wondering whether an operation like `G*G` which is a point multiply another point is possible or not. And if it is possible how can we calculate that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such an operation [is possible](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.897/spring04/L25.pdf).

The ways of calculating that [appear to be different for each curve](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=elliptic+curves+pairing).

Comment: Sounds nice. What about its security? Is this operation reversible by dividing the result to a G?

Comment: That is the [Fixed Pairing Inversion](http://www.pairing-conference.org/2007/invited/Satoh_slide.pdf) problem. $\;$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't have enough points to vote your answer up but it really helped.